# How many GraphQL mutations does it take to change a light bulb?

Tags: graphql, graphql-mutation

I mean, really. How many?

- 1? changeTheLightBulb()
- or 2? removeTheLightBulb() + addNewLightBulb()

Comment: you can run all in one request - order is preserved

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on whether or not you treat this operation as an atomic one. While GraphQL specification doesn't have any specific restrictions on that, one thing is clear: if you don't want to have 'no bulb' as valid state, you should only use one mutation - in your case, `changeLightBulb()`.

Also note that it's quite all right to have both `addLightBulb`, `removeLightBulb`, and `changeLightBulb` in your set of mutations. While you might attempt to reuse domain-specific *types* as much as possible (then again, there are certain caveats for reusing generic fragments, covered well enough in [this article](https://medium.com/reactbrasil/graphql-anti-pattern-in-frontend-clients-5a8f6379813d)), reusing the *operations* just to minimize the code surface is, in general, not a good idea.